# Strange message in my program

Tags: sql-server

I have two program, one running on database A, the other on B, on the same MS SQL server. Both programs almost the same. Both are using executable Compute5.exe (I don't have the source code, that is a company rule, we don't have cpp source code at all)
Program for DB A works OK
The other one from Compute5.exe through the following message

```
**Running IJ 1 of 3:\\nyadpfi\pfi\report\Compute5.exe  \\nyadpfi\pfidata\IJ.682.ICE
I.FYNE4nnc5AM7R.NY10T44.20160607.prm -i:\\nyadpfi\pfi\core\pam_unc.ini
ODBC error in CnctODBC.cpp(329),table=,rc=-1,native=17,sqlstate=08001
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or  access denied.**
```

Does anybody knows what to do?

Comment: I would guess that the SQL Server does not exist, or access to said SQL Server is denied.

Comment: Without the source code, not really. You could try to troubleshoot your connectivity issue by verifying the login parameters you use and making sure that the program is pointed to the correct database.

Comment: Thank you, I will work with DBA on this.

Answer (score 0):

If the program works on one system 1 pointed at DB A and the same code fails on system 2 pointed at DB B, it stands to reason that you have a configuration or environmental issue on system 2 and/or DB B.

See that the user account executing the program has been given access to DB B.
See that the there are no network issues that would prevent system 2 from connecting to DB B. And so on...